# What is it with different behaviours in finding upper bound during algorithm analysis?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I'm learning Algorithm Analysis and Big-O notation. There are these exercise examples for reference:

**Example-1:** Find upper bound for f(n) = 3n + 8

**Solution:**  3n + 8 ≤ 4n, for all n ≥ 8

```
       ∴ 3n + 8 = O(n) with c = 4 and n0 = 8
```

Another One,

**Example-2:** Find upper bound for f(n) = n^2 + 1

**Solution:**  n^2 + 1 ≤ 2(n^2), for all n ≥ 1

```
       ∴ n^2 + 1 = O(n^2) with c = 2 and n0 = 1
```

Now here comes the next example and the one that's bugging me,

**Example-3:** Find upper bound for f(n) = 2n^3 – 2n^2

**Solution:**  2n^3 – 2n^2 ≤ 2n^3, for all n ≥ 1

```
       ∴ 2n^3 – 2n^2 = O(n^3 ) with c = 2 and n0 = 1
```

Why did we use 2n^3 for comparison in the last example?

Means In every example we used greater values i.e. In first example we used 4n because the equation has 3n as maximum limit,

In second example we used 2(n^2), because n^2 was the maximum in that equation.

Now that means in the third equation we should use 3(n^3) instead of 2(n^2).

Maybe I'm not getting something here, Can you elaborate the missing pieces?

And what is the need for c and n0 here. n0 is the point from which we consider the rate of growth for given algorithm but why c? 
I'm new to algorithmic analysis.

Comment: In the expression `f(n) = 2n^3 – 2n^2`, the `n^3` term dominates `n^2` for large values of `n`.  Hence, the formula is overall `O(n^3)`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm asking something else. When we did 2n^3 - 2n^2 >=  2n^2, why didn't we used 3n^2.

Comment: The coefficients in front of the `n` terms don't matter as `n` gets arbitrarily large.

Comment: `n < n^2 < n^3 < n^4....` so when you have multiple of these and large `n`, take the highest power, other will be insignificant in comparison. And since you take only part of the expression, resulting 'quanity' will be less than the original.

Comment: You can use whatever you want as long as it works. In this case, you can use `2n^3` instead of `3n^3` because the lower-order term is *subtracted*; you don't have to compensate for a small but non-zero addition to the higher-order term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terms are replaced so that all the exponents are the same. For an upper-bound, you want to replace them with larger values. Increasing the exponent will produce larger values for positive terms, but for negative terms then you can replace them with 0 instead, removing the term.

For `3n + 8`, `3n + n` is an upper-bound because `8 <= n` for `n > n0`.

For `n^2 + 1`, `n^2 + n^2` is an upper-bound because `1 <= n^2` for `n > n0`.

For `3n^3 - 2n^2`, `3n^3 + 0` is an upper-bound because `-2n^2 <= 0` for `n > n0`.

---

`c` and `n0` are needed because they're part of the definition of Big-O:

```
`f(n) = O(g(n))` means that `f(n) <= c.g(n)` for some c and large enough n
```

By finding values of `c` and `n0`, you can show that some functions fit this definition where `c` is what you need to multiply `g` by to make it larger than `f`.